# Angular Material input validation error messages

Tags: angularjs, validation, binding, pug, angular-material

I'm trying to write an app using Angular-Material and I have a form that has some required fields that needs input validation. I've attempted following the example from [the angular-material page under errors](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input), but when I view the code in the browser, the error messages will still appear even if stuff is entered into the fields

[image: Error messages displayed on the entered fields]

My jade template looks like this:

```
form(name="accountForm")
    div(layout="row",layout-sm="column")
        md-input-container
            label Name
            input(name="acctName",ng-model="account.name",required)
            div(ng-messages="accountForm.acctName.$error")
                div(ng-message="required")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't realize that ng-messages was a separate Angular module. Since this was a Node project, I imported angular messages using npm

```
npm install -S angular-messages
```

Then I modified my angular module code

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```

... and it worked!

[image: validated fields with hidden messages]

Comment: Thanks you saved my life.

Comment: My greatest Respect! Sitting on this for hours.